# Can a recurring email be setup to send to a group?

Tags: email

Can an email to a group be setup to send every week?  We have a weekly event that we want to send the same email to attendees reminding them to come.

Comment: Best way to do it is use schedule reminder. (../civicrm/admin/scheduleReminders?reset=1)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could use schedule reminders for sending e-mails to participants of events.

You could setup the reminder to run a week before the event takes place. I would assume that it will also works with a recurring event.

[image: How to set up scheduled reminders]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried using recurring events, but it created a new event for each week.  Then a separate email reminder had to be created to send out the email.  It was just too cumbersome.

Comment: I don't understand why you have to setup different reminders for a recurring event. It is just one schedule reminder and you could use tokens in the message about when the event is

Comment: When I setup a recurring event for each week for the next year, Civi created 52 separate events.  This meeting could go on for years.  That alone made it too unwieldy for me to use the event reminder.  For example: If the time changed, I would have to change it in each of the 52 events.  Is there another way to create a recurring event?